# Jolt spec to get the details using Dynamic ID from json

Tags: java, json, jolt

[image]Given dynamic **accountId** return the **onlineId** and **signinId** for that specific user.

Input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "request": {
      "body": {
        "inputAccountId": "1234"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "1234",
    "ageGroup": 3,
    "role": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "aa@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "one"
  },
  {
    "accountId": "1122",
    "ageGroup": 3,
    "role": 2,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "bb@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "two"
  },
  {
    "accountId": "2211",
    "ageGroup": 1,
    "role": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "cc@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "three"
  }
]
```

If **accountId** = **1234** or **accountId** could be any account either 1122, or 2211 as well based on use case, then return the output JSON for that accountId.

Jolt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "request": {
        "inputAccountId": "@(3,request.body.inputAccountId)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "request": {
        "inputAccountId": "requestedId"
      },
      "1": {
        "*": {
          "accountId": {
            "requestedId": {
              "onlineId": "onlineId",
              "signinId": "signInId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am not able to get the above code working.. The Java throws error -
java.lang.NullPointerException" when reading the JOLT Spec file.

I also tried ${requestedId} but it goes as numeric, so I added it as requestedId which throws nullPointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following transformation specs :

```json
[
  { // set values of the object keys to their accountIds
    // while taking out the value of request.body.inputAccountId
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "request": {
          "body": {
            "inputAccountId": "inputId"
          }
        },
        "*": {
          "@": "@2,accountId.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "inputId": {
        "*": {
          "@2,&": "[]" // traverse 2 levels to reach 
                         // the value of "inputId" in order
                         // to match with the value of
                         // object keys
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @pcoder but seems there are double input the first one is already within the question and the second one is something like ````{
  "request": {
    "id": "1",
    "body": {
      "inputAccountId": "1234"
    }
  }
}````

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by double input? 
Also, I cannot hardcode the "1234" as you did in the above suggestion.
It could be 1234, or 2211 or any other accountId and based on the "@(1,body.inputAccountId)" it should be taken

Comment: Do you know how to use inputAccountId instead of hardcoded value "1234" ?

Comment: @pcoder Oh I have missed that part OK, and will cancel soon ... But I'm unsure about your exact JSON

Comment: What you have here is correct - 
[
  {
    "request": {
      "body": {
        "inputAccountId": "1234"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "accountId": "1234",
    "ageGroup": 3,
    "role": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "aa@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "one"
  },
  {
    "accountId": "1122",
    "ageGroup": 3,
    "role": 2,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "bb@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "two"
  },
  {
    "accountId": "2211",
    "ageGroup": 1,
    "role": 1,
    "gender": "f",
    "signinId": "cc@aa.com",
    "onlineId": "three"
  }
]

Comment: Now I need a JOLT Spec which returns the account details based on inputAccountID,

Comment: I tried using jolt spec and json on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception
But in the jolt what should i give instead of "1234" is the question. Because it returns "null" if i mention "inputAccountId" variable 

Comment: Check the screenshot i added above

Comment: @pcoder Alright, just edited, and going to bed, take care :)

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks a ton, you have no idea how many days i was struggling with this. Tweaked the jolt to get the onlineId and signinID! Cheers 